# Set up hostname using cloud-init in user-data script in EC2 launch template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hostname

I have a user-data script in a Launch template for EC2 instances.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=analytics-python3-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
#cloud-config
hostname: myhostname;
fqdn: myhostname.example.com;
manage_etc_hosts: true;
```

Despite doing that using cloud-init setup it's not working.

Also tried changing the order, and using just fqdn because I read that it's the only useful value.

```
#!/bin/bash
fqdn: myhostname.example.com;
echo ECS_CLUSTER=analytics-python3-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
```

Edit:

using just cloud-config set up to avoid use two types of script. Despite that ECS doesn't start machine:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
- echo ECS_CLUSTER=analytics-python3-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
- echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
- [ sh, -c, "sudo yum update -y" ]
- [ sh, -c, "sudo yum install -y ruby"]
- [ sh, -c, "sudo yum install -y wget"]
- [ sh, -c, "cd /home/ec2-user"]
- [ sh, -c, "wget https://aws-codedeploy-eu-west-1.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/latest/install"]
- [ sh, -c, "chmod +x ./install"]
- [ sh, -c, "sudo ./install auto"]
hostname: 
- myhostname
fqdn: 
- myhostname.example.com
manage_etc_hosts: 
- true
```

I think the format is the expected one because if I use the below one it works:

```
#cloud-config
runcmd:
- echo ECS_CLUSTER=analytics-python3-cluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
- echo ECS_BACKEND_HOST= >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Comment: If you are combining two types of documents to cloud-init (script and cloud-config), you have to use a multipart-MIME document, you can't use comments. See [this example](https://github.com/ukayani/cloud-init-example/blob/master/README.md#sample-user-data)

Comment: Also, I am pretty sure you need to restart the ECS service after you update ecs.config.

Comment: @jordanm Thanks! Instead of using MIME document I read about runcmd to use sh commands in the cloud-config interpreter. Despite that doesnt change the hostname, neither install the codedeploy agent.  Added mods into the question.